# Trying to use reduce() and lambda with a list containing strings

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to use pythons reduce function on a list containing strings of integers.

```
print int("4")
\\Gives me 4 Good
print reduce(lambda x,  y: x*y,  [2, 3, 4])
\\Gives me 24 Good
print reduce(lambda x,  y: x*int(y),  ['2',  '3',  '4'])
\\Gives me 222222222222 What??
```

I assume that reduce is giving the lambda function something that isn't the actual string in the list? I have no idea why I'm getting 222222222222 at least, would there be an easy way to make the list an int? I guess I could just us another loop but I would still like to know whats wrong with passing the strings.

Comment: I wasn't expecting so many answers in this short of time. Thanks for the help everyone.
For anyone new, I ended up using
`reduce(lambda x,  y: x*int(y),  ['2',  '3',  '4'], 1)` from @Óscar López

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,  y: x*int(y),  ['2',  '3',  '4'])
'222222222222'
```

Okay, here is what happens:

In the first reduce step, the following calculation is done: `'2' * 3`. As the first operand is a string, it simply gets repeated `3` times. So you end up with `'222'`.

In the second reduce step, that value is multiplied by 4: `'222' * 4`. Again, the string is repeated four times which results in `'222222222222'` which is exactly the result you got.

You could avoid this by either converting `x` to an int as well (calling `int(x)`), or by mapping the list elements using an integer conversion in the first place (I actually think that’s more elegant):

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, map(int, ['2', '3', '4']))
24
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, I'm marking this as the answer as it is the most informative.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
reduce(lambda x,  y: x*int(y),  ['2',  '3',  '4'], 1)
```

Notice that I'm passing a third parameter to `reduce`, indicating that the operation should be initialized in `1`, the multiplicative identity. In this way, you only need to convert `y`, the *current* value to `int`, and not `x`, the *accumulated* value.

Comment: +1. That’s indeed a nice solution as well. To add some explanation: The passed `1` in the `reduce` call makes it the default/start value, so the first reduce step is actually `1*int('2')`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up using this as it appears to be the most efficient to me.

Comment: @JustinEgli I also think it's the most efficient, because it doesn't create any intermediate lists (as `map` does).

Comment: @Oscar That's what I thought too.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez In Python 3, `map` doesn’t create a list, but a map object.

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplying string '2' by int 3 which gives string '222'... then string '222' by int 4, which gives string '222222222222'.

You need to convert x to an integer:

```
print reduce(lambda x,  y: int(x)*int(y),  ['2',  '3',  '4'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
multiply = lambda a,b: a*b
listOfInts = map(int, ['2','3','4'])

reduce(multiply, listOfInts)  #output: 24
```

Comment: Even better: `from operator import mul as multiply`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: Thank you, I thought of that, but I would rather write it out for clarity and versatility. I find it tragic that many functions which you'd expect to be in the default namespace have to be imported.